# How does infinite DMRG work?

Tags: condensed-matter, dmrg

iDMRG or infinite-size density matrix renormalization group, is a common technique in condensed matter. It seems that usually people believe that it reliably captures infinite-size behavior.  I have found plenty of resources describing **how** it works (mathematically), but I want a **heuristic/intuitive explanation** for how a system composed of effectively two sites (each with a large tensor) can capture physics that is occurring at all different length scales.